# Ebay API bulkUpdatePriceQuantity for product variations

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

I have a product with some size-variations.

For example root item has sku 20159DA2 and children have for sku 20159DA2-S, 20159DA2-XS, etc

I want to call the method bulkUpdatePriceQuantity but it gives me Bad Request telling me the sku doesn't exists.

Here the example of the json I'm sending to Ebay

```
{
"requests": [{
    "offers": [{
        "availableQuantity": 1,
        "offerId": "115388226132",
        "price": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "value": "69.99"
        }
    }],
    "shipToLocationAvailability": {
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "sku": "20159DA2-XS"
}, {
    "offers": [{
        "availableQuantity": 1,
        "offerId": "115388226149",
        "price": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "value": "89.99"
        }
    }],
    "shipToLocationAvailability": {
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "sku": "20302DA2-S"
}, {
    "offers": [{
        "availableQuantity": 1,
        "offerId": "115388226149",
        "price": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "value": "89.99"
        }
    }],
    "shipToLocationAvailability": {
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "sku": "20302DA2-XS"
}]
```

}

the beam that is coming to me is that I can not use this method for variations. But if so is there any other method I can use to update just the change quantities?

---

### --------USING ReviseFixedPriceItem-------------------

the json I have is

```
{
        "RequesterCredentials": {
            "eBayAuthToken": ""
        },
        "Item": {
            "ItemID": "115809802256",
            "Variations": {
                "Variation": [{
                    "SKU": "STALLION_0",
                    "Quantity": 4
                }]
            }
        }
       }
```

The HttpPost is

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "TOKEN " + EBAY_TOKEN);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");



            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_IT");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                   new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var url = $"https://api.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=ReviseFixedPriceItem";

            string _jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
            HttpContent _httpContent = new StringContent(_jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, HTTPManager.HTTP_POST_CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);

            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, _httpContent).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 }
```

---

### -----------------USING XML---------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
 <ErrorLanguage>it_IT</ErrorLanguage>
 <WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
 <Item>
  <ItemID>115711360327</ItemID>
  <Variations>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_39</SKU>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_40</SKU>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_41</SKU>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_42</SKU>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_43</SKU>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_44</SKU>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_45</SKU>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_46</SKU>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_47</SKU>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
     </Variation>
  </Variations>
 </Item>
```

and use HTTP POST with xml as parameter I get status OK but the response is Ebay Official DateTime, and I need to call ReviseFixedPriceItem

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll");
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            return responseStr;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking the code and the issue about the **SKU doesn't exist**, it appears that you are attempting to use the **bulkUpdatePriceQuantity** method in eBay, but it doesn't support variations, because basically this method is designed for updating price and quantity information for individual items, not variations.

For updating the quantity of variations, eBay provides a separate method called **ReviseFixedPriceItem** instead, which allows you to update specific variation details, including quantity, price, and other attributes.

> So I think you will need to use the Trading API to make requests for revising item details.

Anyway, try this JSON payload for revising the quantity of a variation using the **ReviseFixedPriceItem** method, an example could be:

> In this example, you need to replace "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN" with your actual eBay authorization token and "YOUR_ITEM_ID" with the ID of the item you want to update.

**json**

```json
{
  "RequesterCredentials": {
    "eBayAuthToken": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
  },
  "Item": {
    "ItemID": "YOUR_ITEM_ID",
    "Variations": {
      "Variation": [
        {
          "SKU": "20159DA2-XS",
          "Quantity": 5
        },
        {
          "SKU": "20302DA2-S",
          "Quantity": 10
        },
        {
          "SKU": "20302DA2-XS",
          "Quantity": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Something like that could solve the internal server error:

```js
using (var client = new HttpClient())

{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "TOKEN " + EBAY_TOKEN);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_IT");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var url = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";

    string _jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
    HttpContent _httpContent = new StringContent(_jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    // Console.WriteLine("Sending request to eBay API...");
    // Console.WriteLine("Request URL: " + url);
    // Console.WriteLine("Request Payload: " + _jsonContent);

    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, _httpContent).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Console.WriteLine("Received response from eBay API...");

    var resp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    // Console.WriteLine("Response Content: " + resp);
}
```

> Note that I included a little debbuger (**console.WriteLine**) to print out relevant information during the execution, just uncomment it to check the status of the code.

custom header constants like "HTTPManager.HTTP_POST_CONTENT_TYPE_JSON" and "EBAY_TOKEN" with your actual eBay authorization token and any custom constants used in the code have the correct values assigned to them, I think it should work, because I am not trying to run the code, so I hope.

In the [Ebay official documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html), they refer the construct of XML payload for revising the item variation quantities, a simple example would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>YOUR_ITEM_ID</ItemID>
    <Variations>
      <Variation>
        <SKU>20159DA2-XS</SKU>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      </Variation>
      <Variation>
        <SKU>20302DA2-S</SKU>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
      </Variation>
      <Variation>
        <SKU>20302DA2-XS</SKU>
        <Quantity>8</Quantity>
      </Variation>
    </Variations>
  </Item>
</ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

> Using the constructed XML payload, you can send an HTTP POST request to the url endpoint with the payload as the request body to perform the ReviseFixedPriceItem call.

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I’m going to try this solution and I solo let you know if it works. It appears wonderful

Comment: You're welcome @Martina, yes I hope too, have a good night and let me know!

Comment: I'm getting Internal Server Error, I' going to update my question

Comment: Ok, let me check and modify my answer, maybe we got it.

Comment: Ok like this it not return Internal Server Error but I thing the url is incorrect because the response status is OK but the response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result is Ebay getDate response, so it is not calling the ReviseFixedPrice method.

Comment: You should use the appropriate endpoint for the ReviseFixedPriceItem call, check the URL to use the correct endpoint ... 

var url = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";

Comment: -i know, but I'm not able to find the correct endpoint url. https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html

Comment: I was checking the ebay documentation and they mentioned the use of XML, I added a little snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved with XML and request.Headers with CallName

---

### -----------------USING XML---------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<ErrorLanguage>it_IT</ErrorLanguage>
<WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
<RequesterCredentials>
  <eBayAuthToken>EBAY_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<Item>
  <ItemID>115711360327</ItemID>
  <Variations>
     <Variation>
        <SKU>07000-129-M_39</SKU>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
     </Variation>
     ...
   </Variations>
  </Item>
</ReviseFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

and use HTTP POST with xml as parameter

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll");
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";                
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "ReviseFixedPriceItem");
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "101");
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "613");
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", MY_EBAY-API-APP-NAME);
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", MY_API-DEV-NAME);
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", MY_API-CERT-NAME);
            
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
```